# JAXB Annotation binding XML content as String

Tags: java, jaxb

I want to bind a XML content as a String to the field.
Here is how my xml seems like:

```
<sample>
    <content>
         <p>here is content <b>with bold</b></p>
    </content>
</sample>
```

which should be bound to the following domain object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="news_table")
@XmlRootElement
class Sample {
     @XmlElement(name="content")
     @Column(name="news_content")
     private String content; 
}
```

After unmarshalling, i want to bind the content starts with `<p>` as String type in order to persist formatted text with HTML tags, so that:

```
System.out.println(sample.getContent());
```

must give the following out:

```
> "<p>here is content <b>with bold</b></p>"
```

With @XmlElement annotation i get only empty string "" back from binding operation, since the JAXB recognize the element starts with "`<p>`" as Object to be bound according to my understanding.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `@XmlAnyElement` annotation with a custom `DomHandler`. You can find an example [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html).

Comment: excellent. just wrote my own DomHandler<String, StreamSource> and it works

Answer (score 2):

If it is an option to change the content of the xml file, you could just escape the `<` and `>`. Then JAXB handles it just fine and you also get the correct html string when calling `getContent()` in java.

Here is your xml file with escaped content:

```
<sample>
 <content>&lt;p&gt;here is content &lt;b&gt;with bold&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</content>
</sample>
```

Comment: Agreed.  If the `<p>` tag needs to be handled as text within the `<content>` node, the XML is invalid to begin with.  It needs to be escaped.

Comment: Yes. Another option should be to use CDATA. But as far as I know, JAXB has problem writing CDATA elements.

Comment: @joergl :thanks for ur suggestion. The problem is that the xml which i wanted to bind is a result of StaX parser and the entites are already escaped by StaX API :-S for each sample (there are about 100.000 of them) element escaping the "<"s and ">"s would be a bottleneck in parser. PS: i try to parse a xml about 1GB. In order to increase to performance and decrease memory usage, i read the samples as chunks and bind them immediately.

Comment: If you handle files of this size, you might be better of using StaX or SAX instead of JAXB. StaX and SAX parse the file element-wise and that makes an OutOfMemoryError less likely.